# Can't delete record through Rails

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, destroy

I have a table, say Persons and if I do

```
person = Person.find(:first)
person.delete
```

I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1403:in `block in expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1402:in `each'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1402:in `expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:261:in `build_where'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:124:in `where'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:380:in `delete'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:442:in `delete'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:72:in `delete'
        from (irb):60
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

If I do

```
person.destroy
```

I get

```
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'persons.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `persons` WHERE `persons`.`` = ?
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'persons.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `persons` WHERE `persons`.`` = ?
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:883:in `prepare'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:883:in `exec_stmt'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:490:in `block in exec_delete'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `block in log'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:489:in `exec_delete'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:101:in `delete'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `delete'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:351:in `delete_all'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:94:in `destroy'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:119:in `destroy'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `block in destroy'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:390:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `destroy'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `block in destroy'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `destroy'
        from (irb):61
```

But I can delete the record through MySQL console if I write a SQL delete statement. Any idea what might be happening?

**Other information:**
The Person table has an id column, but the primary key in the databae is a composite key using the id and some other columns. The person model was written by someone else, and has a number of methods written, but none named delete or destroy were written explicitly.

Comment: Do you have an `id` column in the `persons` table? Also can we see the  `Person` model?

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto, I updated a little more in the question. What other info would help?

Answer (score 2):

```
@person = Person.first
@person.destroy
```

If you used a non standard primary key, you will need to set it first:

```
Person.primary_key = 'person_id'
@person = Person.first
@person.destroy
```

If all else fails ... I feel bad for typing this:

```
Person.connection.execute("delete from persons where id = 1 and state_id = 2 and project_id = 5")
```

To save yourself current and future nightmares, you should restructure your database to follow rails standard way of storing data. Person table should contain only unique people with unique id column that is a primary key. New project_assignments table/model should be created to handle assignments with it's own unique id, as well as state_id, project_id, and person_id. Data that belongs with Person should reside in that table, assignment data should be moved to project_assignments etc.

Comment: It has a composite primary key. What is the simplest way to delete a record in such a case?

Comment: You don't have a single column uniquely identifying Person record? Why? What are your columns for composite key?

Comment: I am paraphrasing, but something like (id, state_id, project_id) is the primary key.

Comment: you saying that you have records in persons table with the same id column? id 1 = Frank, and id 1 = Bob? Or are IDs still unique even though you are using composite key? Or do you have records for the same person for different projects in the same table?

Comment: I have the same id for different people like your example. But the total composite keys are different, of course.

Comment: For the record, this is horrible, what does ID mean in this case? If table is called people or persons, it should contain just that, in your case you are storing project assignments but calling it people while not having assignment id of any sort. Since you already not using "rails way" might as well just execute query directly on the table. I will update my answer.

Comment: I agree, I am maintaining a project and the schema should be different in hindsight. But I am really curious as to why given the actual instance of the record, the primary key matters. Is it because of the relationships? If I know exactly where the error occurs, I'd be able to decide the best course of action going forward. Perhaps I need to specify the relationships with specific SQL statements inside the model?

Comment: It's rails convention, when you try to delete an object it is trying to find a record where YourModel.connection.quote_column_name(primary_key) IN (id), note column_name not column_names, it is built to use single column for primary key. It is also assuming that primary_key is ID, while you can overwrite this, it's better to leave it as is. You can see exact rails code here lib/active_record/base.rb, line 690

Comment: It is really unfortunate that Rails developers don't provide a good support for composite keys. The lack of decent support for Foreign Keys also shows how poor is their knowledge about RDBMS good practices. Adding sequential ID columns to relation tables is an anti pattern enforced by Rails.